# AttributeError when using requests.post() in `with` statement

Tags: python, python-requests

A/C python requests [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#advanced), with statement can be used with requests for better speed.

> with requests.get('http://httpbin.org/get', stream=True) as r:
>       # Do things with the response here.

So why is this returning 'Attribute error'?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#101>", line 1, in <module>
with requests.post(url,headers=headers,data=data,stream=True) as post_res:
AttributeError: __exit__
```

code:

```
with requests.post(url,headers=headers,data=data,stream=True) as post_res:
    print(b'Name' in post_res.content)
```

P.S. This is working fine without 'with' statement.

Comment: What version of requests?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart requests-2.9.1

Comment: I have also seen this with `requests.get` in requests-2.9.1

Answer (score 1):

AFAICS a context manager is documented only for `GET` requests, not `POST`. That does make sense since `POST` is not idempotent anyway.

Comment: The context manager operates on the Response object which is the same regardless of request method.